# How to update or even reset rows in persistent table given multiple simultaneous readers?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have an exchangeRates table that gets updated in batch once per week.  This is to be used by other batch and streaming jobs, across different clusters - thus I want to save this as a persistent, shared table for all to jobs share.

```
allExchangeRatesDF.write.saveAsTable("exchangeRates")
```

How best then (for the batch job that manages this data) to *gracefully* update the table contents (actually overwrite it completely) -  considering the various spark job as consumers of it and particularily giving its use in some 24/7 structured streaming streams?

Ive checked the APIs, maybe I am missing something obvious!  Very likely.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `allExchangeRatesDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("exchangeRates")`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect some kind of transaction support from Spark so when there's `saveAsTable` in progress Spark would hold all writes until the update/reset has finished.

I think that the best way to deal with the requirement is to **append** new records (using [insertInto](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@insertInto(tableName:String):Unit)) with the batch id that would denote the rows that belong to a "new table".

> **insertInto(tableName: String): Unit** Inserts the content of the DataFrame to the specified table. It requires that the schema of the DataFrame is the same as the schema of the table.

You'd then use the batch id to deal with the rows as if they were the only rows in the dataset.